# why am i seeing the error The app name is not available in wordpress site creation

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-web-deploy

I am trying to create a WordPress website on azure but when I set the app name an error message of- The app name is not available.help!

Answer (score 0):

It means that name has been taken and you need to choose another name for your app.The app name should be globally unique. Be as descriptive as possible while naming as its a good practice. You can follow this convention region-service-env-codename: WUS-WEBAPP-DEV-MYAPP. This should hopefully make it unique.